# Group numbers in array giving an absolute difference between them with overlapping

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, grouping

I'm having some issues finding a good solution for the following problem

Given an array of numbers, I need to group them giving an absolute distance between the members of the group of no more than 10.

For example:

```
arr = [47,52,56,63]
```

The answer expected is the following:

```
ans = [[56,63], [47,52,56]]
```

The problem I'm having is how to avoid creating single element groups.

Comment: Could you provide a little more details on the conditions that should apply to this grouping.  If the maximum difference is between ordered elements of a group, then the original group already meets that condition (so you could simply split it down the middle and be done). If it is between any two member of the groups then [47,53,56] does not meet the condition.  Also, under what rule is 56 allowed to be in both groups in the answer.

Comment: Why isn't your expected answer = ```[[47,52,56],[52,56],[56,63]]```?

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with a similar problem. I wrote an algorithm that finds groups as long as they don't completely overlap. I hope this is the algorithm you are looking for.

```
arr = [47, 52, 56, 63]
limit = 10

ans = []
last_end = -1
arr.sort()
for i in range(len(arr)):
    start = end = i
    for j in range(i + 1, len(arr)):
        if arr[j] - arr[i] < limit:
            end = j
    if last_end < end:
        last_end = end
        ans.append(arr[start:end + 1])

print(ans)
```